# Create an alternating series of vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
tt <- c("chr1:110363793:G:C", "chr1:110363823:A:G", "chr1:110363849:A:G")
```

How do I create a vector with POS and NEG characters appended alternatively to get this below?

```
"chr1:110363793:G:C_POS", "chr1:110363823:A:G_NEG", "chr1:110363849:A:G_POS", "chr1:110363793:G:C_NEG", "chr1:110363823:A:G_POS", "chr1:110363849:A:G_NEG"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of the recyling of vector with `rep` and `paste`

```
paste0(rep(tt, 2), c("_POS", "_NEG"))
```

-output

```
[1] "chr1:110363793:G:C_POS" "chr1:110363823:A:G_NEG" "chr1:110363849:A:G_POS" "chr1:110363793:G:C_NEG" "chr1:110363823:A:G_POS"
[6] "chr1:110363849:A:G_NEG"
```